# Как сделать, чтобы снимался чекбокс?

Tags: javascript

Способ может показаться костыльным, вместо описанного используют радио-кнопки, но так требует ситуация.
Как сделать, чтобы снимался чекбокс, при выборе соседнего, если они лежат в одном родителе?

```html
<div class="parent-1">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.parent-1 input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    if (this.checked) {
      this.parentNode.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(item => {
        if (item != this)
          item.checked = false;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="parent-1">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

```js
document.querySelector('.parent-1').addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    this.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(item => {
      if (item != e.target)
        item.checked = false;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="parent-1">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```